# Unity Steering Behaviours

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to work with steering behaviours in unity as part of a project and I'm trying to call the Seek behaviour inside of the Pursuit class but I'm finding it challenging and I'm a bit lost.

These are the main classes dealing with the behaviours:

Steering Behaviours Class:

```
public class SteeringBehaviours : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody rb;
    private Steering[] steerings;
    public float maxAcceleration = 10f;
    public float maxAngularAcceleration = 3f;
    public float drag = 1f;

    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        steerings = GetComponents<Steering>();
        rb.drag = drag;
    }


    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 acceleration = Vector3.zero;
        float rotation = 0f;
        foreach(Steering behaviour in steerings)
        {
            SteeringData steering = behaviour.GetSteering(this);
            acceleration += steering.linear;
            rotation += steering.angular;
        }

        if(acceleration.magnitude > maxAcceleration)
        {
            acceleration.Normalize();
            acceleration *= maxAcceleration;

        }

        rb.AddForce(acceleration);
        if(rotation != 0)
        {
            rb.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, rotation, 0);
        }

        
    }
}
```

Steering Class:

```
public abstract class Steering : MonoBehaviour
{
    public abstract SteeringData GetSteering(SteeringBehaviours steeringBehaviours);
}
```

Seek Class:

```
public class Seek : Steering
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject target;

    public override SteeringData GetSteering(SteeringBehaviours steeringBehaviours)
    {
        SteeringData steering = new SteeringData();
        steering.linear = target.transform.position - transform.position;
        steering.linear.Normalize();
        steering.linear *= steeringBehaviours.maxAcceleration;
        steering.angular = 0;
        return steering;
    }
}
```

Pursuit Class:

```
public class Pursuit : Steering
{
    [SerializeField] private float maxPrediction = 2f;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject target;


    public override SteeringData GetSteering(SteeringBehaviours steeringBehaviours)
    {
        SteeringData steering = new SteeringData();

        Vector3 direction = target.transform.position - transform.position;
        float distance = direction.magnitude;
        float speed = GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.magnitude;
        float prediction;
        if(speed <= (distance / maxPrediction))
        {
            prediction = maxPrediction;
        }
        else
        {
            prediction = distance / speed;
        }

        Vector3 predictedTarget = target.transform.position + (target.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity * prediction);
        //Seek
        steering.linear = predictedTarget - transform.position;
        steering.linear.Normalize();
        steering.linear *= steeringBehaviours.maxAcceleration;
        steering.angular = 0;
        //

        return steering;
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me what's the most correct way to use the Seek behaviour class inside of the Pursuit class to replace the code between the commented lines?

Thank you.